# php jquery mysql-better way fo some kind of load more

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i find s good way for load more data from the mysql but i am looking for better way to do that.
this is jquery and php code in index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var comco = 2;
    $("button").click(function(){
        comco = comco + 2;
        $("#comnts").load("ld_comco.php",{
            comnco:comco
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div  id="comnts">
<?php 
$qq="SELECT * FROM t_users limit 2";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
    echo $fff['id'];
    echo $fff['email'];
}
?>
</div>
<button>load more</button>
```

and the ld_comco.php file:

```
$comnco=$_POST['comnco'];
$qq="SELECT * FROM t_users limit $comnco";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
    echo $fff['id'];
    echo $fff['email'];
}
```

in this way, i have to repeat the php-mysql code twice in two files. can I write this code once in a file? 
thanks

Comment: You can use `$( "button" ).trigger( "click" );` in place of your first `php-mysql` code so you only have it  once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is inefficient as it can load a lot of records at once. You better use offset clause in your sql query to make possible to load just 2 records each time you click load more.

In the below code, aside from retrieving just 2 records at once, the first php+mysql code was removed and replaced by jQuery button click trigger.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var comco = 2;
  var offset = 0;
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "ld_comco.php",
        data: { comnco: comco, offset: offset }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        $("#comnts").append(msg);
      });
    offset = offset + comco;
  });

  $("button").trigger("click");
});
</script>

<div  id="comnts">

</div>
<button>load more</button>
```

In the PHP document, I added offset clause for your sql string so you can retrieve successfully just 2 (unique) records at once.

**ld_comco.php**

```
$comnco=$_POST['comnco'];
$offset=$_POST['offset'];

$qq="SELECT * FROM t_users limit $offset, $comnco";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
    echo $fff['id'];
    echo $fff['email'];
}
```

Comment: in this method again uses two mysql code.but when i delete the select.php file it works but it gives this error: Warning: include(select.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp2\htdocs\l4\ld_comco.php on line 1

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'select.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp2\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp2\htdocs\l4\ld_comco.php on line 1

Comment: You have to remove line - `include 'select.php';`